# How to inject query parameters using camel REST DSL?

Tags: apache-camel

Actually I am playing with apache-camel **2.15.2**, the [REST DSL](http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html) available since Camel 2.14 is not complicated. However I can't find in the official documentation how to retrieve a query parameter, basically I would like to target my REST service in this way:

```
http://myServer/myService/myMethod?myQueryParam=myValue
```

Is that possible, or is there any workaround ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Camel uses the REST/HTTP component of choice (restlet, jetty, servlet, netty-http, spark-rest, etc) which maps query parameters as Camel message headers.

So yes you can with the rest-dsl exposes a REST service where clients can call it with query parameters, which is then mapped to Camel message headers during routing.